nginx: client_max_body_size works only AFTER the file is uploaded
Our server is set up using nginx as reverse proxy and a part of our routes has the client_max_body_size 500M directive.
The issue is that nginx doesn't seem to check the content-length header, it just uploads the file and then when the upload reaches 500MB it cuts it off and returns a "Request entity too large" error.
Is there any way to have it check header first and return error based on that?
Does the position of the client_max_body_size command in the location block matter? It's the last one:
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        client_max_body_size 500M;
    }


Content and headers provided by clients are not trusted (because they can easily be forged) so from a security and implementation perspective it makes a lot more sense to actually measure what a client attempts to upload before generating an error

HBruijn: ok, but that's what the client_max_body_size directive is for. if the header is faked, it will only load 500M, not X GB or howerver big the file is. but, IF the header exists, why doesn't it read it and refuse upload on the basis of it?
